# L5.1: Casting parameters as INT before query works in one server, not the other

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm working with Laravel 5.1 and I have defined relationships in my models appropriately.  When I do:

```
$warehouses = Auth::user()->warehouses
->where('activity_id', $request->activity_id)
->where('company_id', $request->company_id);
```

I get a result in my local server, but an empty collection in testing server.  I learned that if I do this:

```
$company_id = (int)$request->company_id;
$activity_id = (int)$request->activity_id;
$warehouses = Auth::user()->warehouses
->where('activity_id', $activity_id)
->where('company_id', $company_id);
```

I get an empty collection in my local server but I get results in testing server.
Is this a configuration thing? I don't remember changing anything related to this. Is it MySQL related?  Testing database is a dump from local database and id fields are integer, auto increment and unsigned.
I'd appreciate any help

Comment: show what you have in Auth::user()->warehouses in your localserver and testing server, maybe, Auth::user() doesn't have warehouses?

Comment: Is the php version the same on both machines?

Comment: @esperant I does have warehouses, it's the same set of data on both servers, one gets results when the other doesn't

Comment: @phaberest php version on local server is 5.5.30 (is running OS X 10.11.3) and test server is  5.5.30 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: That's really strange, but could be related to the fact you are running it on a different OS. I'd suggest you to use a vagrant VM as your local web server (look for Laravel Homestead).

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this happens to anyone else, I solved my own question.  What I did was change the way the query was made and use a filter instead, like this:

```
$warehouses = Auth::user()->warehouses->
   filter(function ($item) use($request) 
   {
   return ($item->activity_id == $request->rdActivity 
      AND 
      $item->company_id == $request->company_id);
   });
```

This seems more natural and true to Laravel coding style and best of all: it works